# Error while requesting a transaction

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

When I requesting a CXTansaction in CXStratCallAction it showing the error message as  `"Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=1 "(null)" "`. Can anyone explain this Error message.

Answer (score 9):

From the header `<CallKit/CXError.h>`:

```
typedef NS_ERROR_ENUM(CXErrorDomainRequestTransaction, CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionError) {
    ...
    CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorUnentitled = 1,
    ...
} API_AVAILABLE(ios(10.0));
```

So error code 1 corresponds to `CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorUnentitled`.

**This error is usually returned when an app lacks the `voip` iOS App Background Mode.** To fix this, open Xcode's Capabilities tab for the app target and enable the "VoIP" background mode, or add 'voip' to the `UIBackgroundModes` array within the app's Info.plist.

(I have filed a request in Apple's bug tracker to mention this in the documentation, Radar 35903988.)

Answer (score 1):

> The app isn’t entitled to perform the actions in the requested transaction.

Refer the link for [error codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxerrorcoderequesttransactionerror.code)